# plt.xticks automaically show up to 3 digits

Tags: rounding

I am creating subplot (10x10). Some of the xticks or yticks show long numbers, up to 6 digits after comma (0.0023444477 etc). How can I automatically set up tick up to 3 digits after comma, so all ticks are 0.00x? I have different ranges for each plot.
Thanks for any help